# Running several Python pandas scripts from a single python file

Tags: python, pandas

I have several python scripts such as `test1.py`, `test2.py`. These scripts do not contain any functions or a modules but simple pandas scripts. I want to run both `test1.py`, `test2.py` from a single file such as `test3.py`. So that I just need to run `test3.py`and not other files. What steps do I need to follow to achieve this? This question is different from other questions because I don't want to use modules import functionality since my scripts do not have functions in it.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a shell script, or GNU parallel: `parallel python ::: test1.py test2.py test3.py` Or you could use `subprocess` module.

Comment: you also might want to check out runpy

Comment: Addressing your edit.  Importing a script, runs it....